# CSS Won't even apply

Tags: html, css

I'm having a really really weird problem with a web app I'm programming. Basically, nothing has worked, and I've had to continually reduce the level of complexity of it trying to get *something* to work. The problem I'm having now is that for some reason my CSS won't apply.

I have it linked, and I made sure the ID I used is correct and everything, but it just does not apply the css. Heres the code:

manage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Blog Manager</title>
    <link rel='stylsheet' type='text/css' href='manage.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='prototype.js'></script>  
    <script type='text/javascript' src='shadowbox-prototype.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='shadowbox.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = Shadowbox.init();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
    <div id='loginbox'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='username' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

manage.css

```
#loginbox {
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    background-color: #999999;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

Am I missing something small? I've tried in firefox and chrome so I know its not some weird browser problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This contains a typo:

```
<link rel='stylsheet' type='text/css' href='manage.css' />
```

Change `stylsheet` to `stylesheet`.

Comment: :D a good one. this is the reason why I add words that are not really words (e.g. stylesheet) to my Eclipse spell-checking dictionary. Gets underlined when misspelled. (Although wouldn't recommend for MS Word ;))

Answer (score 2):

link rel='stylsheet'

remember to use firebug to test your css and validate your html

Answer (score 2):

In your `<link>` tag in manage.php, change:

```
<link rel='stylsheet' type='text/css' href='manage.css' />
```

to:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='manage.css' />
```

(Note the typo in 'stylesheet')